# Export all symbols when Clang cross-compile for Windows

Tags: windows, dll, clang, cross-compiling

I am using Clang to cross-compile for Windows.

I don't want to have to put `__declspec(dllexport)` in my code. I want to tell Clang to export all my symbols in the dll that it builds for Windows.

In gcc, I believe this is by using the flag --export-all-symbols.

Comment: lld supports `-export-all-symbols` (single dash!) and you may need clang `-fvisibility=default`. But I couldn"t get that to work on Windows yet at least.